# Running a jar with the right version of scala

Tags: scala

I have a scala project that I can run with sbt. Now I want to execute it as a stand alone app. How can I run it with the scala command and ensure the right version of everything, in particular the scala-library and JVM?

PS: Just to clarify what I mean by an example from ruby.
I write some ruby script which I use routinely. For example, to apply updates a bit more cleanly then the OS does.

When I wrote the script I used ruby 1.8.3. ( Making version numbers up here as an example. ) I used the command line `ruby my_script`.

Now the version is ruby 2.0.1. The script will not run under this ruby because of language changes. So I use the command line `ruby1.8.3 my_script`.

Or rather I embed it in the shebang line.

Simalarly I want to run a jar using `scala my_jar.jar` but it was a built using a scala version 2.8.3 and will not run with that command. How do I make scala use the right version?

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can try here:

1) The [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) will create an executable. For example, you can create an RPM or Debian package.

2) You can create an "uber jar" using (say) [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and package all your dependencies into a fat jar. You can specify a main function to be executed when running the jar (using the JVM `java -jar a-jar-to-execute.jar` command).

Both of the above are very active and widely used SBT plugins.

After your create the jar everything is in byte-code and you don't need to worry about Scala versions at that point. It will run as long as the Java (jvm) versions are compatible.

Comment: I'm trying sbt-assembly as we speak.  check out my additional comment in case I made myself misunderstood.